# pipe inside child component not called when input changed

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a custom pipe to filter an array. The pipe is used inside a child component, data to child component is passed through input parameter. When the input data is changed, pipe is not called. Is there anything I have to do differently when using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush inside child component.

**Edit**

In the example below, product-list-container gets products from ngrx store. The data is passed into product-list component through input parameter.

In product-list component, i have a filter that is for filtering out rows based on some criteria. The issue I am seeing is that, when input value changes pipe function is not called. Pipe is getting called only once on component load.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-list-container',
  template: `
    <app-product-list [productList]="productList$ | async"></app-product-list>
  `
})
export default class ProductListContainer implements OnInit {
  public productList$: Observable<Product[]>;
  constructor(public store: Store<AppState>) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.productList$ = this.store.select('productList');
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let product of productList | filterActiveProduct">
   // More code here 
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: changeDetectionStrategy.onPush
})
export default class ProductList {
  @Input() productList: Product[];
  constructor() {
  }
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'fromNow'
})
export class filterActiveProduct {
  transform(products: Product[], args: Array<any>): string {
    return products.findAll(p => p.isActive);
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please include the relevant code - rather than a description of said code - in the question.

Comment: @cartant I have addd sample code above. Thanks!

Comment: Found a potential solution. If I set pure: false on the pipe, it gets called when the input changes.

Comment: If the product list is changing, the pipe should be called. I suspect you could have a bug elsewhere. Perhaps you are mistakenly mutating the array's content? (E.g. adding an item?) If the array instance is the same, `OnPush` will cease change detection at that point and the pipe would not be called. I don't think you should have to use an impure pipe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

that because your pipe is `Pure pipes`.

> Angular executes a pure pipe only when it detects a pure change to the
>   input value. A pure change is either a change to a primitive input
>   value (String, Number, Boolean, Symbol) or a changed object reference
>   (Date, Array, Function, Object).
>
> Angular ignores changes within (composite) objects. It won't call a
>   pure pipe if we change an input month, add to an input array, or
>   update an input object property.

using `Impure pipes` in your case:

> Angular executes an impure pipe during every component change
>   detection cycle. An impure pipe will be called a lot, as often as
>   every keystroke or mouse-move.
>
> With that concern in mind, we must implement an impure pipe with great
>   care. An expensive, long-running pipe could destroy the user
>   experience.

FilterActiveProduct:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterActiveProduct',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterActiveProduct {}
```

ProductList:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let product of productList | filterActiveProduct">
   // More code here 
    </div>
  `,
})
export default class ProductList {
  @Input() productList: Product[];
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Following this document page: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: Thanks, making the pipe impure fixed the issue.